# To get the Form from its Processhandle

Tags: c#, winforms, process

Is there any way to get the Form from its Processhandle ?
Some thing like this.

```
Form form = (Form)Form.FromHandle(_process.MainWindowHandle);
```

But this is not working.

Comment: It might help if you elaborated on how the line is not working, is it throwing an exception, returning null?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is the target form of your own design, or is it from a third-party application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/netfxbcl/thread/9F7657AB-A415-4390-A11F-CED8AF702C13), that only works for window handles owned by your process.  You can't use `Form.FromHandle` to get a form from some other process.

See also: [How to use Control.FromHandle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303812/how-to-use-control-fromhandle)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this from within a process.  Trying to grab a `Form` or `Control` from another process won't work.

Can you give us some more information as to what you're trying to do here with the `Form`?  There may be a better way to accomplish it.